# Android mediaplayer mute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

```
private MediaPlayer mp_file;
```

I have mediaPlayer to play mp3 files in my project, it works fine...

```
mp_file.release();
mp_file = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.zh_02); 
mp_file.start();
```

I want to create (to make it work) a button called `mute_on` and `mute_off`.... How can I do it? By clicking this button all mp3 files in project will mute_off...or mute_on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code worked for me,

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mp.start();
```

for Mute

```
mp.setvolume(0,0);
```

& Unmute or full volume

```
mp.setvolume(0,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
mediaplayer.start();
mediaplayer.pause();
```